# Key error appearing while evoking for loop

Tags: python, json

When I try to loop trough items in json and some of them doesn't contain element which I am evoking I am getting Key Error.

```
for i in range(200000): #(amount of lines in file):
 data["tasks"][i]["Assignments"] = [data["tasks"][i]["Assignments"][0]]
    
KeyError: 'Assignments'
```

How can I avoid this error?

Comment: You could use try/except clause to ignore the error and keep iterating over further elements.

Answer (score 1):

Just use try/except as mentioned in the comments

```py
for i in range(200000): #(amount of lines in file):
    try:
        data["tasks"][i]["Assignments"] = [data["tasks"][i]["Assignments"][0]]
    # if KeyError occurs, just skip the line
    except KeyError:
        continue
```